# CSS - does reusing the same image perform like two separate images

Tags: css, image, performance

I have an image I want to set as a background, with `background-attachment: fixed` element, but I'd like to set it on two divs, which scroll at different speeds. So as you scroll it 'appears' that both divs are giving little peeks at the same image hiding behind it all. However, it would actually need to be two separate divs with the same image set as the background.

I'm curious, will using the same image twice be less clunky than two separate images? I know the render will be relatively the same, but in terms of the page loading, will It save some performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will, if the URL is exactly the same.

Browsers will cache media resources if the URL is the same, so using the same image in two places is better than using two separate images.